# JSON return value

Tags: php, jquery, json

Currently I am having issue with returning some values from PHP to jQuery - not sure how to do it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#testForm').submit(function(e){
    $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

        $('#submit').val('Submit');

        if(msg.status){
            $('#testForm').html(msg);
        }
        else {
            $('#testForm').html("fail");
        }
    },'json');

});

});

<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'html'=>$name." : ".$email));
echo '{"status":1,'.$name.'}';
?>
```

I would like to return the `name` variable value from PHP to jQuery once `status = 1` means success, but I'm still having no luck in doing it.

Comment: Why are you not using the commented-out line?

Comment: it has special char on a name try htmlentities($name)

Comment: `echo '{"status":1,name:"'.$name.'"}';` Try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON has a very strict syntax.

In your case, however, you're failing because you're not even specifying a property name, you just have a bare value with no quotes.

Just use `json_encode`, it will handle all edge cases for you.

Comment: how does the syntax looks like for the json_encode if i would like to set status 1/0 together with the data return from php to jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are returning a valid json string?

From this instruction:

```
echo '{"status":1,'.$name.'}';
```

Assuming that $name is a plain string, for example "hello", you will return this json string:

{"status":1, hello}

And this is invalid.